# What is the preferred way to bind a radcombobox in a radgrid?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid, radcombobox

I've seen a lot of questions close to this but haven't found my answer. Here's the key points of my example below:

- RadGrid has a GridTemplateColumn
- GridTemplateColumn has a RadComboBox in it's EditItemTemplate
- RadComboBox is bound to an ObjectDataSource and had a RequiredFieldValidator
- SelectedValue='<%#Bind("SomeValue")%>' seems to work but causes validation issues
- Setting RadComboBox1.SelectedValue in ItemDataBound event seems to be working

Is binding with code in the ItemDataBound the best way to do this? What's interesting is that setting SelectedValue='<%#Bind("SomeValue")%>' on the aspx page has the SelectedValue already set by the time I get the ItemDataBound but for some reason, a RequiredFieldValidator fails in edit mode when doing this unless I set the value AGAIN in ItemDataBound. Below is a stripped down version of my code.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="rgTasks" runat="server" AllowAutomaticInserts="false" AllowAutomaticUpdates="false" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="Id">
        <CommandItemSettings ShowRefreshButton="False"></CommandItemSettings>                
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" UniqueName="EditCommandColumn"></telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Id" ReadOnly="True" UniqueName="Id" DataType="System.Int32" Visible="false"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="TaskTypeId" HeaderText="Task" DataField="TaskTypeId" DefaultInsertValue="">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("TaskType.Name")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbTaskTypeId" runat="server" EmptyMessage="Select TaskType..."
                        DataSourceID="odsTaskTypes" DataValueField="Id" DataTextField="Name" SelectedValue='<%#Bind("TaskTypeId")%>'> 
                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvTaskTypeId" runat="server" ControlToValidate="rcbTaskTypeId" ErrorMessage="Task Type is required" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsTaskTypes" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetTaskTypes" TypeName="CAPAModel.CAPARepo.DataRepo"></asp:ObjectDataSource>

Protected Sub rgTasks_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridItemEventArgs) Handles rgTasks.ItemDataBound
    If ((TypeOf e.Item Is GridEditableItem) AndAlso e.Item.IsInEditMode) Then
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "TaskTypeId").ToString) Then
            Dim rcbTaskTypeId As RadComboBox = e.Item.FindControl("rcbTaskTypeId")
            rcbTaskTypeId.SelectedValue = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "TaskTypeId")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I saw some relevant questions but am looking for an explanation of how I SHOULD be doing this and why. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've gone back and forth with Telerik support on this and their suggestion was to just do it the way I'm doing it. Considering that I'm binding the control in the code, I can probably get rid of `SelectedValue='<%#Bind("TaskTypeId")%>'` like so:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbTaskTypeId" runat="server" 
     DataSourceID="odsTaskTypes" DataValueField="Id" DataTextField="Name" > 
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

...and then just keep the code as is:

```
Protected Sub rgTasks_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridItemEventArgs) Handles rgTasks.ItemDataBound
    If ((TypeOf e.Item Is GridEditableItem) AndAlso e.Item.IsInEditMode) Then
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "TaskTypeId").ToString) Then
            Dim rcbTaskTypeId As RadComboBox = e.Item.FindControl("rcbTaskTypeId")
            rcbTaskTypeId.SelectedValue = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "TaskTypeId")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occured because you have set two different datafield as DataValueField and SelectedValue. I suppose you want to show another field as selected other than data in DataValueField and DataTextField. Please take a look into the following code snippet.

ASPX:

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="test" FilterControlAltText="Filter RegistryValue column" HeaderText="test" SortExpression="test" UniqueName="test">
          <EditItemTemplate>
              <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" Runat="server" DataSourceID="odsTaskTypes" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id" >
              </telerik:RadComboBox>
          </EditItemTemplate>
          <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="RegistryValueLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RegistryValue") %>'></asp:Label>
          </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

C#:

```
protected void gridiew1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
    {
        GridEditableItem editItem = (GridEditableItem)e.Item;
        RadComboBox combo = (RadComboBox)editItem.FindControl("RadComboBox1");
        combo.SelectedItem.Text = (string)DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "TaskTypeId").ToString();      
    }      
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, Saritha. I should have been more clear and have edited my question. The code above functions fine. However,  if I don't reset RadComboBox1.SelectedValue in ItemDataBound, the RequiredFieldValidator will fire incorrectly unless I change the value in the RadComboBox. What's odd is that when I'm resetting the SelectedValue, it's actually already there.